How can I make a completly simple powder simulation, without any extra effectors but just a plane and the powder?
I was searching too long for a totally simple tutorial on how to make a powder simulation. I just need a picture of it, of how the powder is on the ground and completly still like this:

But any video I stumbled on is just a plain tutorial of how to make a sand/powder simulation for a sand clock or something else. They were not very useful and my simulation gets more slippery than static.
I just want a tutorial with the powder and a plan without any discussion here like "Uh, but you can download a model","Uh, just download a picture","Bruh, just follow the tutorial as needed and make some differences(I'm not that advanced into simulations, I don't understand most of the things yet)".
Thanks

By risking saying something you don't want to read, but what exactly do you need a simulation for if you just want a picture of powder lying on the ground? Make a mesh forming the basic shape, then instance a lot of small particles on it...

That's what i meant. It won't be that "realistic". And I don't need another argument. Im sick of that kind of discussion on any forum

Well, I know this is not great but I'm not in the mood to spend hours getting it better since you don't want to discuss this anyway... just a quick try: powder heap

You could also subdivide a plane and sculpt it, then give it a material with very little noise?
